# Can't log in to Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, login

I was trying to log in to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) (with the Stack Exchange account) and keep getting the "Oops! Something Bad Happened" page indicating there is something wrong.

Is there something going on right now?

I tried this both on Chrome (v31) and IE8.

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox with a Google account. I've logged out and now I can't log in any more.

Comment: @Stijn next time use incognito mode/private browsing instead :)

Comment: @AlvinWong Good point :P

Comment: Reproduced in IE 9, Firefox 24, Chrome 31 and my Android browser.

Comment: We're working on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were significant updates to a few of our core components.  Area 51 was left in the dark about these changes - exactly as it should be when dealing with aliens.

All should be better now so feel free to try again!

Comment: Trust No One...

Comment: Thanks, this works now.